# Sql Server - Best Practices for Growing Database Files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log, best-practices

I have been monitoring file growth via the data collector in sql server 2008 r2 for two weeks. The database is growing consistently at around 35(MB)/Day. The DB has not yet hit the initial size of 2 GB.

The DB files auto growth is set to 5MB and I would like to try a different approach, so I am looking for suggestions and or comments.

There is a tuning task that runs every-week on Sunday night at 1:30 AM. The task will:

- Check Database Integrity
- Shrink the Log File – (This is ok because logging mode is Simple)
- Shrink Database
- Reorganize Index
- Rebuild Index
- Update Statistics
- Clean Up History

I would like to add two more steps to the weekly tuning plan:

1. Grow the database file by 500 MB if the used space reaches a certain threshold or total size.
2. Grow the log file by 250 MB (after the shrink) if the used space reaches a certain threshold of total size.

By placing the growth burden in offline hours, I hope to gain performance by reducing the number of auto-growth events during heavy loads.

I have two questions relating to auto growing files.

- The best place to put the file grow steps would be prior to the current steps or after?
- If I use the `ALTER DATABASE|MODIFY FILE` to grow the file then how can I determine if `SpaceUsedInFile >= (TotalFileSpace-@AllowanceThreshold)`?

Comment: Your DB should have enough size that it *never* grows. None the less, make sure [Instant File Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935(v=sql.105).aspx) is enabled.

Comment: @Remus while ideal, are you saying that you've pre-sized every database perfectly throughout your career? There is always going to be some guess-work involved and adjustments to be made. I will agree that growth should be controlled and not just left to do so 7 times a day.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I favor simplistic, [hyperbole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole) advice. In time I learned it sticks better. Most users can't handle the 'it depends' and those that do can figure out on their own that there are shades of gray in between black and white...

Comment: @Remus sure, but telling them they always need to pre-size their database correctly may lead them to panic when they can't - or to severely over-allocate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you say "over-allocate" like it's a bad thing :)

Comment: @Dan well if you take space that will never be used by that database and it prevents another database from being sized correctly... there's such a thing as buying a car that's too powerful too, though most of us macho guys would never admit that in public. :-)

Comment: @DanAndrews: over-allocation can have effects 'downstream'. Think a dev trying to restore the DB on his machine only to discover it needs two new 1TB drives for 1Gb of data...

Comment: I'm only playing the devil's advocate.  However, HDs are cheap.  Lost time in production for reconfiguration and performance loss is expensive.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I resemble that DEV that you speak of.  That's why we should use more virtual machines, we could just fire up another instance as a DEV machine.

Comment: Virtual machines still require disk space, and just because it is cheap does not mean it is easy to provision.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be aiming to auto-grow as little as possible. Seven times a day is excruciating, even with instant file initialization.

Don't do a Shrink Database. Ever. Shrinkfile, maybe, but only after an extraordinary event. Shrinking it just to grow again is an exercise in futility and should actually be called auto-fragment.

If recovery model is simple, there is no way on earth you should need to grow your log file by 250 GB. The used space in the file will clean itself out automatically over time, unless you started a transaction a month ago and have no intentions of ever committing it or rolling it back.

So my advice would be:

Auto-grow the data file manually during a quiet period to a size that will accommodate several months of growth. What are you saving it for in the meantime?

Set the auto-growth increment for the data file to something relatively small (so that it doesn't interrupt users when it does happen), and alert on this event (you can catch it in the default trace, for example, or through extended events). This can tell you that you are hitting the high point you estimated and it is time to grow manually again. At this point you will want to keep this manual in case you want to add a new file / filegroup on a different drive to accommodate the space, since eventually you will fill the current drive.

Auto-grow the log file to, say, twice the largest it's ever been. It shouldn't auto-grow further unless there is some abnormal transaction holding things up. You should monitor for this event as well, so that you know about them.

Comment: Thanks for the input...I will ues your advice for growing the log file and monitor it for a while. I incorrectly used GB for MB in the autgrow size. I agree and don't think the Shrink Database is doing what it was intended to do. At the end of the year the DB reaches 15GB, at the time the job was created we were running out of room for backups.

Comment: +1 for *should be called auto-fragment* :-) Have you launched a Connect issue for that already? :-)

Answer (score 12):

Auto growth is something that you should try to avoid if possible. The issue is you have no control over when the growth can happen and your system can take a serious hit while it does so.

Set your file size to something sensible for a month or so and monitor your growth rate from there work out how much space you estimate for X amount of time and set your size to that + a margin of error.

I've set up a simple monitoring job that will alert me when the file size hits a predefined maximum before auto growth. You could use something like this:

```
SELECT instance_name,
       [Data File(s) Size (KB)],
       [LOG File(s) Size (KB)],
       [Log File(s) Used Size (KB)],
       [Percent Log Used]
       into ##Logsize
FROM
(
   SELECT *
   FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
   WHERE counter_name IN
   (
       'Data File(s) Size (KB)',
       'Log File(s) Size (KB)',
       'Log File(s) Used Size (KB)',
       'Percent Log Used'
   )
     AND instance_name = 'database your interested in' 
) AS Src
PIVOT
(
   MAX(cntr_value)
   FOR counter_name IN
   (
       [Data File(s) Size (KB)],
       [LOG File(s) Size (KB)],
       [Log File(s) Used Size (KB)],
       [Percent Log Used]
   )
) AS pvt 
go
declare @logsize int
Select @logsize = [Percent Log Used] from ##Logsize

If @logsize > the maximum percent you want the log to fill too i.e 90
    BEGIN
        --Do your thing here
    END

Drop table ##Logsize
```

This could of course be scheduled as a job.

Comment: I remove the "AND instance_name = 'database your interested in" so it returns all databases. Then use a count where the log size is a above a threshold in the IF statement. If the count is higher than 1 I do a sp_send_dbmail with a select name statement from the temp table to email the names of the logs above the limit.